# How to duplicate a website built with GoDaddy website builder?

Tags: godaddy

GoDaddy built a nice website: 
GoDaddy charged a pretty penny.
However it uses GoDaddy's proprietary web builder.

I wish to clone said website to another url, which is also hosted by Godaddy.
Godaddy wishes to charge another pretty penny as if they were building the site from scratch.

Is there a way of cloning that doesn't cost thousands of dollars?

Answer (score 1):

If you own the files, you can use [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or another FTP client to access your server and download the source files. Once you have the source files you can then upload them to any other server you want.

You will need the following to connect with filezilla:

- IP address of your website/webserver
- FTP username and password (usually setup and defined by you in your cPanel or there may be a default account)
- Port number to connect with (22 for hostmonster)

Keep in mind you will need the entire site for it to function properly.
If your site is feature rich and filled with advanced coding, you may need to migrate a database and adjust settings at the new domain to get it working.
Yours looks like its mostly html/css and javascript, so the contents of the public_html folder should be all you need.

[Connecting to Your Hosting Account with FileZilla (FTP)](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/104/connecting-to-your-hosting-account-with-filezilla-ftp?countrysite=ca)

Comment: nice answer! I can't believe I forgot to mention that it uses Godaddy's website builder/content management system. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes that definately will complicate the process a bit. Ill look into it.